# How to use Rails Low Level Cache in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have an application which calls an API and authenticates using a token. I need to store this token and refresh it every so often, so I am using `Rails.cache.fetch` to do so in a custom class for handling the API calls. This works great on my local dev machine, but in production it is erroring. I am running a Mac for my dev machine and production is on Ubuntu 18. Here is the code that raises the error:

```
def authenticate
    Rails.cache.fetch(@token, expires_in: 2.hours.to_i) do
      login_uri = @base_uri + "auth/login"
      auth_response = HTTParty.post(login_uri, body: { username: ENV["API_USERNAME"], password: ENV["API_PASSWORD"] } )
      @token = auth_response.parsed_response["token"]
    end

  end
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Errno::ENOTDIR (Not a directory @ rb_file_s_rename - 
 (/var/www/myapp/releases/20190424134348/tmp/cache/.00020190424-1954-lgpvq5, 
  /var/www/myapp/releases/20190424134348/tmp/cache/001/000/)):
```

It looks like Rails is attempting to rename or move the cache file for some reason. Looking at the server the `/001` directory is there, but the subdirectory `/000` does not exist.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly but you should really look into using Redis or Memcached as your cache store. Memcached is the fastest of the 2 options.

Comment: Thanks - I believe I am now using memcached in production, but it's throwing different errors. I am going to check to make sure I have it configured correctly.

Comment: Have yout tried running `RAILS_ENV=production rails tmp:cache:clear`, just for fun at least

Comment: What `@token.cache_key` outputs?

Comment: you should be running memcached in development too then

Comment: I finally got it to work by switching to Redis. I couldn't get memcached or memory to work in production. Redis works perfectly, though.